# In python's Bokeh, how can I remove text above the plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

With the following code:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.output_file('output.html', mode="cdn")
```

I get an html file with my graph(s); but it has the text:

```
You have 1 plots
Close All Plots
```

Above the graph.

Is there a way to produce html output without this text?

Answer (score 3):

As of Bokeh 0.5 there is a much more convenient [embed](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/reference.html#module-bokeh.embed) module, which should provide the functionality you desire.

In your specific case, I would suggest the following setup:

1. Load BokehJS from CDN at the top of your page (or in the head)
   `<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.5.1.js"></script>`
2. In the Python script generating the plots, run

   `bokeh.embed.components(bokeh.plotting.curplot(), bokeh.resources.CDN)`

   for each plot. That will return a tuple with a `<script>` string containing the plot generation code, and a `<div>` string you can place anywhere on your page as a target.